# VF Page to upload file to two records

Tags: visualforce

I'm working on a VF page which uploads a file on to an account record and contact record.

The vf page has an upload file component as well as two look up fields.

I've got help initially from a previous q but I'm running into other issues:

1. Unable to pass account's record id to an account lookup field on visualforce page (currently accessing vf page after clicking custom button on account page)
2. Unable to pass the record id of value's entered lookup fields to the file's parent id field for file upload
3. Debug logs not showing in developer console

VF Page

```
apex:page controller="AttachFileToMultipleRecordsController">
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageblock>
        <apex:pageblockbuttons>
            <apex:commandbutton action="{!uploadAttachments}" value="Upload File"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!cancelUpload}" value="Cancel" immediate="true"/>
        </apex:pageblockbuttons>
        <apex:pageblocksection title="Attachment" columns="1">
            <apex:inputFile value="{!accountAttachment.body}" filename="{!accountAttachment.name}" />     
            <apex:outputLabel value="The maximum file size is 10 MB." />            
        </apex:pageblocksection>
        <apex:pageblocksection title="Choose Your Records" columns="1">
            <apex:inputField label="Account" id="Account" value="{!Cas.AccountID}" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputField label="Contact" id="Contact" value="{!Cas.ContactId}" required="true"/>
            <apex:param value="" name="cas.AccountID"/>
            <apex:param value="" name="cas.ContactID"/>
        </apex:pageblocksection>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class AttachFileToMultipleRecordsController {
public Account Acc                  { get; set; }
public Contact Ctct                 { get; set; }
public Case Cas                     { get; set; }
public Attachment accountAttachment { get; set; }
public Attachment contactAttachment { get; set; }
public String AccID                 { get; set; }
public String ConID                 { get; set; }

public AttachFileToMultipleRecordsController() {
    // Set variables
    Acc               = new Account();
    Ctct              = new Contact();
    accountAttachment = new Attachment();
    contactAttachment = new Attachment(); 
}

public void AccID(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    // Set Account ID in Lookup field
    Cas.AccountID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    System.debug('ID passed to variable ' + Cas.AccountID);
}  

public PageReference PassingParameter() {
    String conID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cas.contactId');
    List<Contact> cons = [SELECT ID
                            FROM Contact
                           WHERE id=:cas.contactID
                           LIMIT 1]; 
    ConID = cons.get(0).id;
    System.debug('List size: ' + cons.size());
    return null;
}

public PageReference uploadAttachments() {
    // Upload both Attachments;
    accountAttachment.ParentId = cas.AccountId;
    contactAttachment.ParentId = conId;
    contactAttachment.Body     = accountAttachment.Body; 
    contactAttachment.Name     = accountAttachment.Name;
    System.debug('Contact ID passing to variable: ' + conID + '. Body: ' + accountAttachment.Body + '. Name: '  + accountAttachment.Name);

    insert new List<Attachment>{ accountAttachment, contactAttachment
    }; 
    System.debug('File Account ID: ' + accountAttachment.ParentId + '. Contact ID: ' + contactAttachment.ParentId); 

    // Return to Account record
    return new PageReference('/'+Acc.Id);
}

public PageReference cancelUpload() {
    // Back to Account record
    {
      PageReference retPage = new PageReference('/'+apexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id')); 
      return retPage;
    }    
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean by Unable to pass record ID, can you elaborate more on the problem(s) you are facing? any errors? have you tried debugging?

Comment: @glls added debugs and more info into the original post...the debugs are not showing in the console, so that's another issue.